# Yii: How to update multiple models using only 1 form 1 model and 1 action?

Tags: php, yii

I have a model `website` and a model `url`.

Each `url data` is attached to a `website data`. A `url` is related to a `website` via a `website_id`.

On my web app, I need to check the data before accepting it.

I want to see on screen the entire data regarding a `url data` and I managed to do this.

Now, I also want to update the entire data that is listed on screen.

On screen I have the entire `url data` and `website data`, but when I try to save the data, the `website data` is empty.

My logic was to add to the `url` model a property: `public $website;`

And within the `url` model, a method `aftersave`:

```
protected function afterSave() {
    $w = null;
    $w = Website::model()->findByAttributes(array('id' => $this->website_id));
    //echo '<pre>';
    //print_r($w);
    print_r($this->website);
    $w->link = $this->website['link'];
    $w->domain = $this->website['domain'];
    $w->description = $this->website['description'];
    $w->save(false);
    die;
    return parent::afterSave();
}
```

and here is the important code from the `_form` file:

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'will_expire'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'will_expire',array(0=>'No',1=>'Yes')); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'will_expire'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model_website,'link'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model_website,'link'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model_website,'link'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model_website,'domain'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model_website,'domain'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model_website,'domain'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model_website,'description'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model_website,'description'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model_website,'description'); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Are these linked via a foreign key? Does Yii's ORM/DBAL not support cascading saves of related objects?

Comment: yes, they are related; a url is related to a website via website_id

Comment: Is there always going to be a Website model returned for the given ID in your Url::afterSave? `$w` will be `null` if not. Is that being saved elsewhere in a preceding step?

Comment: A `url` will always belong to a `website`. A url `id` will always belogn to a website `id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be small mistakes like `w` instead of `W`, object property instead of array;

Ok, so let me teach you how to do this;

I have 2 models: `Url` and `Website`.

`Url` model has a foreign key `website_id` and a relation to model `Website`;

Within the `Url` model I have a property called `website` and i declared it like: `public $website = array();`;

The data gets added thru a `bookmarklet` that uses a `API` so the data will be there when the admin comes to update/check it;

In the `Url` model i have a method `afterSave`:

```
protected function afterSave() {
    $w = null;
    $w = Website::model()->findByAttributes(array('id' => $this->website_id));
    if($w)
    {
    $w->link = $this->website['link'];
    $w->domain = $this->website['domain'];
    $w->description = $this->website['description'];
    $w->save();
    }
    return parent::afterSave();
}
```

where `$this->website` gets populated in the `UrlController` on `actionUpdate` like:

```
public function actionUpdate($id, $type = 'update') {
    $model = $this->loadModel($id);

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if (isset($_POST['Url'])) {
        $model->attributes = $_POST['Url'];
        $model->website = $_POST['Website'];
        if ($model->save())
            if ($type == 'update')
                $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $model->id));
            else
                $this->redirect(array('/admin/url/approvePublicLink'));
    }

    $model_website = Website::model()->findByAttributes(array('id'=>$model->website_id));

    $this->render('update', array(
        'model' => $model,
        'model_website' => $model_website,
    ));
}
```

and gets passed to the `afterSave` method later;

this is the `_update` view:

```
<div style="padding:20px 20px;">
<h1>Update Url, Website, Keywords ...</h1>
<?php echo $this->renderPartial('_form', array(
'model'=>$model,
'model_website' => $model_website,
)); ?>
</div>
```

and this is the `_form` view that gets rendered partial:

```
<div class="form">

<?php

$form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'url-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
));
?>

    <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'website_id'); ?>
        <?php echo CHtml::link($model->relation_website->domain,$model->relation_website->domain,array('class'=>'avia','target'=>'_blank')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'website_id'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'link'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'link',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>255)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'link'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'title'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'title',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>255)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'title'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'description'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'description',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>255)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'description'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'important'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'important',array(0=>'Normal',1=>'Important')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'important'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'views'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'views'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'views'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'created'); ?>
        <?php echo $model->created; ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'created'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'updated'); ?>
        <?php echo $model->updated; ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'updated'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'will_expire'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'will_expire',array(0=>'No',1=>'Yes')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'will_expire'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model_website,'link'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model_website,'link'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model_website,'link'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model_website,'domain'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model_website,'domain'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model_website,'domain'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model_website,'description'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model_website,'description'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model_website,'description'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'status'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'status',array(-1=>'Banned',0=>'Normal',1=>'Active')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'status'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Save'); ?>
    </div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div><!-- form -->
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

There are few questions:

1. Is the relation `url` and `website` being defined in the model such that `$url->website` of a existing url gives you valid website record?
2. You form shows, you are not using any website_id, means that you are creating a new website record for every URL, means `$w = Website::model()->findByAttributes(array('id' => $this->website_id));` will always return NULL

I assume you have defined a relation of `website` within your `URL` model.
Suggested function from my understanding:

```
protected function afterSave() {
    //data is already assigned by the caller
    $w = null;
    $w = Website::model()->findByAttributes(array('id' => $this->website_id));
    if($w)
    {
        Yii::log("updating existing website data","info");
        $this->website->save();
    }
    else
    {
        Yii::log("creating new website data","info");
        $this->website->save();
        $this->website_id = $this->website->website_id;
        $this->update(array('website_id')); //save the relation
        Yii::log("created new website {$this->website_id}","info");
    }
    return parent::afterSave();
}
```